# coloured Box Diagram with arrows and signs

Tags: diagrams

could someone help me out with this diagram? Which package would you advice and what would the code look like?
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: you can look on the `tikz` package and examples (http://www.texample.net). One such -- http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fault-tree/

Comment: As Amit suggests, `tikz` is excellent. Another option is, if you don't mind, `xfig` and a converter (`fig2dev`, `fig2pstricks`, `fig2tikz`). You can embed the resulting codes to tex or create a separate pdf to `\includegraphics`. That's how I usually do diagrams unless I have to edit the contents frequently.

Comment: what you try so far?